# gulp serve showing error when trying to create sharepoint clent development

Tags: sharepoint, gulp

gulp serve showing error like below

> fs.js:27
>   const { Math, Object } = primordials;
>                            ^
>   Reference: primordials is not defined
>       at fs.js:27:26
>       at req_ (E:\Sharepoint\react-app\node_modules\natives\index.js:143:24)
>       at Object.req [as require] (E:\Sharepoint\react-app\node_modules\natives\index.js:55:10)
>       at Object. (E:\Sharepoint\react-app\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:1:37)

Comment: Can you include the gulp file so we can more effectively help?

Comment: 'use strict';

const gulp = require('gulp');
const build = require('@microsoft/sp-build-web');
build.addSuppression(`Warning - [sass] The local CSS class 'ms-Grid' is not camelCase and will not be type-safe.`);

build.initialize(gulp);